# jQuery Golf Scoreboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of struggling a bit with the proper jquery to iterate through my table of values and perform the following calculations...

I have one row of user inputs with the class input or could be an array.

Then one row for par values with class = par, could be an array. and one row for hole result ( par-strokes ).

Then I would like to put the total in the last td of the row that has class rtot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGTHz/1/

```
<style>
table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse:collapse; width:600px; }
td {border:1px solid #ccc; padding:3px 5px 3px 3px; text-align:center; height:24px; }
.name{ font-weight:bold; }
#s1{ color:#ccc; }
.par2 { display:none; }
</style>

<table>

<tr id="par"><td class="nd name"></td><td class="par">4</td><td class="par">3</td><td class="par">5</td><td class="par">3</td><td class="par">5</td><td class="par">4</td><td class="par">2</td><td class="par">3</td><td class="par">4</td><td class="par">3</td><td class="par">5</td><td class="par">3</td><td class="par">5</td><td class="par">4</td><td class="par">2</td><td class="par">3</td><td class="par par2">4</td><td class="par par2">3</td><td class="par par2">5</td><td class="par par2">3</td><td class="par par2">5</td><td class="par par2">4</td><td class="par par2">2</td><td class="par par2">3</td><td class="par par2">4</td><td class="par par2">3</td><td class="par par2">5</td><td class="par par2">3</td><td class="par par2">5</td><td class="par par2">4</td><td class="par par2">2</td><td class="par par2">3</td><td class="nd"></td></tr>

<tr class="r"><td class="nd name">Smith / Williams</td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="nd rtot"></td></tr>

<tr class="s"><td class="nd name">User input</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">4</td><td class="input">4</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">4</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">4</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">4</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="nd rtot"></td></tr>

<tr><td class="nd name">Smith / Williams</td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="val"></td><td class="nd rtot"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="s"><td class="nd name">User input</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="input">2</td><td class="input">1</td><td class="input">3</td><td class="nd"></td></tr>

</table>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var sum = 0;

$('tr .input').each(function () {

    var ind = $('.input').index(this);
    var par = Number($('.par').eq(ind).html());
    var sc = Number($('.input').eq(ind).html());
    var tot = sc-par;
    sum += tot;
    $('.val').eq(ind).html(sum);

});

});


</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: The sum is not resetting after the first row, also I don't know how to access the rtot (total) td of each row. My process just feels sloppy and I know there is a better way but I can't seem to find any examples that are similar to what I am trying to do.

Comment: $('tr .input') is going to contain all the td elements in 2 rows.  is that what you wanted? that look like it's going to throw off your indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum1 = 0;
    var sum2 = 0;
    $('tr .par').each(function (ind) {

        var par = Number($('.par').eq(ind).html());
        var sc1 = Number($('.t1 .input').eq(ind).html());
        var sc2 = Number($('.t2 .input').eq(ind).html());
        var tot1 = sc1 - par;
        $('.t1 .val').eq(ind).html(tot1);
        var tot2 = sc2 - par;
        $('.t2 .val').eq(ind).html(tot2);

        sum1 += tot1;
        sum2 += tot2;
    });

    $('.t1 .rtot').html(sum1);
    $('.t2 .rtot').html(sum2);

});
```

here is the html behind your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wVtjz/

Answer (score 1):

you can reset the sum like this and access the rtot like this

```
$('tr.s').each(function () {
   var sum = 0;
   $(this).find(".input").each(function(){
       var ind = $('.input').index(this);
       var par = Number($('.par').eq(ind).html());
       var sc = Number($('.input').eq(ind).html());
       var tot = sc-par;
       sum += tot;
       $('.val').eq(ind).html(sum);
   });    
   $(this).find(".rtot").html(sum);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPmhm/)

Comment: Very much appreciated!Thank you Abraham Uribe!

Comment: you're welcome that only work with "tr.s .rtot" not with "tr.r .rtot"